# build and pass list of types to variadic templates

Tags: c++, c++14, variadic-templates

I'm very new to meta-programming and I'm experimenting with some examples.

I've designed a variadic template class as follows:

```
template <typename TA, typename... TB>
class A
[...]
```

This could be instantiated simply by passing different types like

```
A<Class1, Class2, Class3> * a = &(A<Class1, Class2, Class3>::instance());
```

where the pack TB only contains `Class2` and `Class3`.
Now, what I would like to achieve is to define in my header file a list of default types and build it gradually using `#ifdef` definitions. I'll make an example

```
// concept of list of types
template<class... Ts>
struct typelist{};

// concatenating two typelists
template<class... Ts, class... Us>
auto concat(typelist<Ts...>, typelist<Us...>) -> typelist<Ts..., Us...>;

static typelist<> defaultTypelist;

#ifdef MACRO1
defaultTypelist = concat(defaultTypelist, typelist<Class2>);
// or something like defaultTypelist.push_front(Class2);
#endif
#ifdef MACRO2
defaultTypelist = concat(defaultTypelist, typelist<Class3>);
// or something like defaultTypelist.push_front(Class3);
#endif
```

By doing that, in my main I would like to instantiate my object as follows:

```
A<Class1, defaultTypelist> * a = &(A<Class1, defaultTypelist>::instance());
```

The main problem I see here is that I'm not able to gradually append types to `defaultTypelist` since it was declared in the beginning at empty template `typelist<>`. The compiler also returns an error if I try to pass an empty typelist as second parameter.
This may be trivial but so far I was not able to solve this, mainly because, as a beginner in meta-programming, compiler errors are not very helpful to me.

For this project, I have to use C++14 and below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Big fat warning: don't do this.

The reason I'm saying, it'll change during the code. As you gradually add types, you'll end up `defaultTypeList` having multiple meanings in different places of the code.

That said... Can it be done? Of course,

```
#define DEFAULT_TYPE_LIST typelist<>()

// ...
#ifdef MACRO1
static constexpr auto macro1_prev_dtl = DEFAULT_TYPE_LIST;
#undef DEFAULT_TYPE_LIST
#define DEFAULT_TYPE_LIST concat(macro1_prev_dtl, typelist<Class2>())
#endif

// ...
#ifdef MACRO2
static constexpr auto macro2_prev_dtl = DEFAULT_TYPE_LIST;
#undef DEFAULT_TYPE_LIST
#define DEFAULT_TYPE_LIST concat(macro2_prev_dtl, typelist<Class3>())
#endif
```

... then use `DEFAULT_TYPE_LIST` wherever you'd like to access the *current* state of the list.

Comment: Hi @lorro, thank you for your answer. Redefinition shouldn't be a problem since I'm designing an interface and this variable is only created once in the beginning where I already have every `#ifdef` condition. But anyway, is there an actual safe way to do this? I also forgot to explicit that for project reasons I'm forced to use C++14 and below but constexpr should be available since C++11. I've red its functionality changed a little between c++11, c++14 and c++17

Comment: Honestly I'd make a typelist with all types, then filter it with a compile-time `bool` args that's `MACRO1..N`. But the above should also work.

Comment: I get a compilation error `error: 'macro1_prev_dtl' does not name a type`. Could this be caused by the fact that I'm using c++14?

Comment: @Codexy It's because I missed the `auto` in declaration. Fixed it, shoud work now.

Comment: Sorry my bad, still have some compilation errors. First I got `error: call to non-'constexpr' function [...] concat [...]`. So I modified the concat function adding the `constexpr` keyword before the return type so it can be evaluated at compile time but now what I got is an error when I try to insert the macro in the object declaration: `error: type/value mismatch at argument 2 in template parameter list for template [...]`

Comment: And this: `note: expected a type, got 'concat<, Class2>((macro1_prev_dtl, typelist<>()), (typelist<Class2>(), typelist<Class2>()))'`

Comment: @Codexy `template<class... Ts, class... Us>
constexpr auto concat(typelist<Ts...>, typelist<Us...>) -> typelist<Ts..., Us...> { return typelist<Ts..., Us...>(); }`